# I cannot access createFile method from any folder. I want to save image file in gdrive from a URL

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to upload image file in specific drive from any url. I cannot get the createfile method from folder. that method is not even showing.

Here is my code:

```
    function downloadFile() {

      var fileName = "";
      var fileSize = 0;

      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://drive.google.com/open?id=1M_OcuVU71GAizO3TnzLKE24VnqEfiOws', {muteHttpExceptions: true});
      var rc = response.getResponseCode();

      if (rc == 200) {
        var fileBlob = response.getBlob()
        var folder = DriveApp.getFilesByName('101');
        if (folder != null) {
          var file = createFile(folder)
          fileName = file.getName();
          fileSize = file.getSize();
        }
      }

      var fileInfo = { "rc":rc, "fileName":fileName, "fileSize":fileSize };
      return fileInfo;
    }

    function createFile(folderName) {
      var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName);
      folder.createFile(fileBlob;
    }
```

Comment: If you had miscopied the script, please update to your latest script? Because for example, at the script of `folder.createFile(fileBlob;`, there is no `)`. I think that in this case, when the script is saved, an error occurs. If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a few errors in your code:

1. In your `createFile()` function, you are not closing the parentheses to the `folder.createFile(fileBlob)` call.
2. You are not passing the blob to your `createFile()` function.
3. `folderName` is a FilesIterator object (see return type of [DriveApp.getFilesByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilesbynamename)), but afterwards you use it as a string.

Your code with both errors fixed should look like below:

```js
function downloadFile() {

  var fileName = "";
  var fileSize = 0;

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://drive.google.com/open?id=1M_OcuVU71GAizO3TnzLKE24VnqEfiOws', {muteHttpExceptions: true});
  var rc = response.getResponseCode();

  if (rc == 200) {
    var fileBlob = response.getBlob();
    var folderIterator = DriveApp.getFilesByName('101');
    if (folderIterator.hasNext()) {
      var file = folderIterator.next().createFile(fileBlob);
      fileName = file.getName();
      fileSize = file.getSize();
    }
  }

  var fileInfo = { "rc":rc, "fileName":fileName, "fileSize":fileSize };
  return fileInfo;
}
```

See that your `createFile()` function has been removed as it was not needed. To check whether the folder exists, `hasNext()` method is called in the iterator, and afterwards `next()` is used to retrieve the actual folder.

Also, consider that if you please, you can pass any name you want to the newly created file using [`createFile(name, content)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createfilename,-content)